Problem with Plot3D in Mathematica for plotting functions involving parabolic cylinder, exp, and error functions
I have the following problem to make plots of two functions:
Eq.1
$$
\begin{align*}
   A_1(a, \Delta, \omega_0) 
   &= 1 - \frac{2\Delta^2}{\omega_0} + \frac{a^2}{\omega_0^2}
   - \left[1 + \frac{a^2 - 3 \Delta^2}{\omega_0^2}\right] a
   \int_0^\infty j_0(\omega_0 \tau) \,
     \exp\left(-a \tau - \frac{\Delta^2 \tau^2}{2}\right)
    \,\mathrm{d}\tau \\
   &\quad-\left(\frac{a^2 \Delta^2}{\omega_0^3} - \frac{2\Delta^4}{\omega_0^3}\right)
     \int_0^\infty \sin(\omega_0 \tau) \,
       \exp\left(-a \tau - \frac{\Delta^2 \tau^2}{2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}\tau \\
   &\quad-\frac{a\Delta^2}{\omega_0^2}
     \int_0^\infty \cos(\omega_0 \tau) \,
       \exp\left(-a \tau - \frac{\Delta^2 \tau^2}{2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}\tau
\end{align*}
$$
where $j_0$ is the spherical bessel function of the first kind.
and
Eq.2
$$
\begin{align*}
    &A_2(a, \Delta, \omega_0) 
      =1 - \frac{2\Delta^2}{\omega_0} + \frac{a^2}{\omega_0^2} \\
    &-\left[1 + \frac{a^2 - 3 \Delta^2}{\omega_0^2}\right] \frac{a}{\omega_0} 
      \operatorname{Re}{\left[
      \lim_{n \rightarrow 0}
      \left\{
        \frac{\mathbb{i}}{2} \exp\left(\frac{a^2 - \omega_0^2}{4 \Delta^2}\right) 
        \Gamma(n)
        \left[\exp\left(-\frac{\mathbb{i}\,\omega_0 a}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
           D_{-n}\left(\frac{a - \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)
           - \exp\left(\frac{\mathbb{i}\,\omega_0 a}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
           D_{-n}\left(\frac{a + \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)
        \right]
      \right\}
      \right]} \\
    &\quad-\left(\frac{a^2 \Delta^2}{\omega_0^3} - \frac{2\Delta^4}{\omega_0^3}\right) 
     \operatorname{Re}\left[
       -\frac{\mathbb{i}\,\sqrt{2 \pi}}{4 \Delta} \\
       \left\{
          \exp\left(\frac{(a - \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0)^2}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
             \left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a - \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)\right)
          - \exp\left(\frac{(a + \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0)^2}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
             \left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a + \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)\right)
       \right\}
     \right]\\
    &\quad-\frac{a\Delta^2}{\omega_0^2}
     \operatorname{Re}\left[
       \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{4 \Delta}
       \left\{
          \exp\left(\frac{(a - \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0)^2}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
             \left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a - \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)\right)
          + \exp\left(\frac{(a + \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0)^2}{2 \Delta^2}\right)
             \left(1 - \Phi\left(\frac{a + \mathbb{i}\,\omega_0}{\Delta}\right)\right)
       \right\}
    \right]
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathbb{i}$ is $\sqrt{-1}$, $\Gamma(n)$ is a gamma function, $D_{\nu}(z)$ is the parabolic cylinder function, $\Phi(z)$ is the error function, and $\operatorname{Re}[z]$ is the real part of $z$.
When I plotted those two functions in the region $(a, \omega_0, \Delta) = [2, 4] \times [2, 4] \times \{1\}$, they gives the same results.
But when I used the region  $(a, \omega_0, \Delta) = [10^{-5}, 1] \times [10^{-3}, 1] \times \{0.03\}$, there is a blow-up along $a$-axis.
I implement them in Mathematica 12.3.1.0
Here is my code for the implementation of those two functions:
Afunc1[a_?NumericQ, Delta_?NumericQ, omega0_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{result, term1, term2, term3, term4, tau, argExp, 
   tol = -600},
  term1 = -2.*(Delta/omega0)^2 + (a/omega0)^2;
  argExp = -a*tau - (Delta*tau)^2/2.;
  term2 = -(1. + (a/omega0)^2 - 3.*(Delta/omega0)^2)*a*
    NIntegrate[
     SphericalBesselJ[0, omega0*tau]*
      If[argExp > tol, Exp[argExp], 0], {tau, 0., \[Infinity]}];
  term3 = -(a*(a/omega0)*(Delta/omega0)^2 - 
       2.*Delta*(Delta/omega0)^3)*
    NIntegrate[
     Sin[omega0*tau]*If[argExp > tol, Exp[argExp], 0], {tau, 
      0., \[Infinity]}];
  term4 = -((a*Delta^2)/omega0^2)*
    NIntegrate[
     Cos[omega0*tau]*If[argExp > tol, Exp[argExp], 0], {tau, 
      0., \[Infinity]}];
  result = 1 + term1 + term2 + term3 + term4]

 Afunc2[a_?NumericQ, Delta_?NumericQ, omega0_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{result, term1, term2, term3, term4, n, argExpa, tol = -600},
  term1 = -2.*(Delta/omega0)^2 + (a/omega0)^2;
  argExpa = 0.25*((a/Delta)^2 - (omega0/Delta)^2);
  term2 = -(1. + (a/omega0)^2 - 3.*(Delta/omega0)^2)*a*
    Re[Limit[-I/2
        If[argExpa > tol, Exp[0.25*((a/Delta)^2 - (omega0/Delta)^2)], 
        0] Gamma[n] (
        Exp[-(I/2.)*(omega0/Delta)*(a/Delta)]*
          ParabolicCylinderD[n, (a - I*omega0)/Delta] - 
         Exp[I/2.*(omega0/Delta)*(a/Delta)]*
          ParabolicCylinderD[n, (a + I*omega0)/Delta]), n -> 0]];
  term3 = -((a/omega0)^2 (Delta/omega0) - 2.*(Delta/omega0)^3) Re[-((
       I Sqrt[2.*\[Pi]])/4.) (
       Exp[
          0.5*((a/Delta) - I (omega0/Delta))^2]*(1. - 
           Erf[(a - I*omega0)/(Sqrt[2.]*Delta)]) - 
        Exp[0.5*((a/Delta) + I (omega0/Delta))^2]*(1. - 
           Erf[(a + I*omega0)/(Sqrt[2.]*Delta)]))];
  term4 = -((a*Delta)/omega0^2)*Re[Sqrt[2.*\[Pi]]/4. (
       Exp[
          0.5*((a/Delta) - I (omega0/Delta))^2]*(1. - 
           Erf[(a - I*omega0)/(Sqrt[2.]*Delta)]) + 
        Exp[0.5*((a/Delta) + I (omega0/Delta))^2]*(1. - 
           Erf[(a + I*omega0)/(Sqrt[2.]*Delta)]))];
  result = 1 + term1 + term2 + term3 + term4]

I really appreciate any suggestion from you. Thank you. :)

The first omega0 in term1 of Afunc1 and Afunc2 don't look like they should be squared.
